# Filterbar doesn't reset data when empty React-Native

Tags: react-native, filter, asyncstorage

I'm making app in react-native with posting and getting data from asyncStorage, everything works well, i can save a data and get it but I have problem to set filter bar properly. It works only in one direction, for example when I write something inside input, i see results which fits, however when i delete characters from input, data doesn't back to normal and i see nothing eventho filterBar is empty, does anyone has suggestions how to fix it?

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: "",
      data: [],
      error: ""
    };
  }

 handleTextChange = search => {
    this.setState({ search });
    let data = this.state.data;

    data = data.filter(el => el.name.match(search))
    this.setState({data:data})

  };

_displayAllData = () => {
    return this.state.data.map(el => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text >
            Nazwa: <Text>{el.name}</Text>
          </Text>

          <View>
              <Text>
                Ulica: <Text>{el.street}</Text>
              </Text>           
            </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };

render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="find results"
              onChangeText={this.handleTextChange}
              value={this.state.search}
            />
          </View>

          {this._displayAllData()}

          <View>
            <Text>{this.state.error}</Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are performing filtering to your original list(Data Array). Try one thing, take **two arrays**, one for to **show filter data list** and one for **an original data list.**

Please see below code. Let me know if there is any problem with this solution.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: "",
      data: [], 
      filterData:[], // take one more list to show filter data list
      error: ""
    };
  }
```

Initially, add same data to both list:

```
componentWillMount(){
 this.setState({data: //set your data, filterData: //set same data})
}
```

HandleSearch Data:

```
 handleTextChange = search => {
    this.setState({ search });
    let data = this.state.data; 
    //apply filter to your original list
    data = data.filter(el => el.name.match(search))
    this.setState({filterData:data}) //set filter result in your filterData list.

  };
```

Use **filterDataList** to show your list

```
_displayAllData = () => {
    return this.state.filterData.map(el => {
      return (
        <View>
          <Text >
            Nazwa: <Text>{el.name}</Text>
          </Text>

          <View>
              <Text>
                Ulica: <Text>{el.street}</Text>
              </Text>           
            </View>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };
```

Comment: ah I felt that data has to be duplicated first but totally didn't know how to do it next, everything works perfectly! thank you so much mate:)